# How to consume Soap Rpc encoded in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, soap-rpc-encoded

Hello I managed to generate classes from wsdl using axis 1.4.But I am stuck at invoking services. I tried to used WebServiceTemplate and jaxb2marshaller but there is no request class generated. So I tried created request class manually based on the generated response class. But it is getting any response from server.It says xmlrootelement is not found. So i think jaxb2marshaller is not the correct way to invoke service since it is old rpc encoded soap wsdl. Suggest me the idea to invoke service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
when using axis 1.4
I found the solution to invoke methods.It is simple 2 line code.

SomeService service=new SomeServiceLocator().getSomeServicePort();

Sample sample=service.fetchSample();